# My session automatically closes when starting a certain type of App

Tags: crash, logout, debug

I am new to Ubuntu.

I just did an install of Ubuntu alongside Windows. Everything works perfectly except for one thing: Ubuntu crashes.

It's not a regular event, but it happens when I open settings, or when I wanna change the background via the right click on the desktop, or when I want to play a song.

I tried the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>REISUB</kbd> thing, but it logged me off again on the next session while clicking on a song to make it play. These are the type of action I did when it logged me off, I haven't tried other ways to make me log off.